# UNAUTHENTICATED: Credentials require channel with PRIVACY_AND_INTEGRITY security level. Observed security level: NONE

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin, firebase-cli

Using firebase admin sdk with java to connect my backend server to firestore.

This is my initialization method which does the firebase setup

```
 public void initialize() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS);
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
       
    }
```

My project is working fine when i am running with cloud firestore but when i try to run with firestore local emulator by adding the environment variable **FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST** i am getting the following issue

```
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauthenticatedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Credentials require channel with PRIVACY_AND_INTEGRITY security level. Observed security level: NONE
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionResponseObserver.onErrorImpl(ExceptionResponseObserver.java:82)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.StateCheckingResponseObserver.onError(StateCheckingResponseObserver.java:86)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectStreamController$ResponseObserverAdapter.onClose(GrpcDirectStreamController.java:149)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
```

Comment: This looks similar, have you taken a look at it?
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1363

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also having this issue... Looks like there is a bug that was fixed here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/452

However... if you only import `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.1.0` it appears to use `google-cloud-firestore:1.35.0` which doesn't have the fix in it!

You need to specify both dependencies to get this working correctly with the emulator in `build.gradle`

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.1.0"
implementation "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:2.1.0"
```